# ImportError: No module named 'ruamel' running Anaconda

Tags: anaconda

I am using MacOS X 10.11.2 and I want to install Anaconda 3, so that I downloaded the Anaconda3-4.3.0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg from [here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). After I installed,  I tried runnging this but I got the error like the following.

```
S0106602ad06e3352:bin jouk$ conda
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/common/configuration.py", line 38, in <module>
    from ruamel_yaml.comments import CommentedSeq, CommentedMap
ImportError: No module named 'ruamel_yaml'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/conda", line 7, in <module>
    from conda.cli.main import main
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/cli/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .main import main  # NOQA
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 46, in <module>
    from ..base.context import context
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..common.configuration import (Configuration, MapParameter, PrimitiveParameter,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/conda/common/configuration.py", line 40, in <module>
    from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedSeq, CommentedMap  # pragma: no cover
ImportError: No module named 'ruamel'
S0106602ad06e3352:bin jouk$
```

I tried solving this error with this workaround ([here](https://superuser.com/questions/1159792/conda-traceback-no-module-named-ruamel-yaml-comments)). But in this case is for the case in which I installed Anaconda twice to two places in local. But, I didn't do that. What is my problem?

Comment: IIRC, Anaconda doesn't install to the `/Library` directory, so its possible that `conda` is using the wrong Python. What is your `$PATH`?

Comment: @darthbith my $PATH is /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: And can you post the output of `which conda`?

Comment: @darthbith /Users/jouk/anaconda/bin/conda

Comment: Try putting `/Users/jouk/anaconda/bin` at the front of your `$PATH`. That will fix it, I think (hope)

Comment: @darthbith thanks, the installer added the anaconda path to $PATH. But I used the shell I already opened. thanks!!